# how to hide / show line from php designer IDE

Tags: php, ide, designer

How to hide or show line from PHP designer.

example:

this is show lines

```
function () {
  line 1
  line 2
}
```

this is hide lines

```
function () {...}
```

you can help me please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since phpDesigner is paid software, I do not have it (nor am I on a windows platform). But this feature is called Code Folding or Code Collapsing.

In NetBeans there is usually a small plus (or minus) to the left of code that can be folded / collapsed clicking on that usually allows the code to be collapsed or expanded. There is usually a menu option for this as well. Give those a shot and hopefully that helps you get on your way.

**EDIT**

Given the lack of Documentation (not sure if when you buy the software you get insider access) here [phpDeigner Wiki Documentation](http://wiki.mpsoftware.dk/doku.php/home/documentation), I would be wary about even purchasing the product, in my opinion. I like items that have a bit more documentation to them.

Answer (score 2):

If you are going to code xhtml and javascript at the same time, Php designer is one of the best php IDE's out there.
Unfortunately code folding is not available yet. It is planned for the 8.1 release per the following tweet:

https://twitter.com/#!/phpeditor/status/109542551857545216